# I get 403/404 trying to connect to APIC's on-premises Developer Portal using ip-address

Tags: ibm-cloud, apiconnect

I can log into the Portal using its host name, but not url. Why?
Example:

- https://developer.think.ibm/ works
- https://192.168.225.20/ returns a 403 and 'nginx'

My 'on-premises' cloud consists of 4 vms that were provided in a workshop in IBM South Bank in June 2016. I am in the process of refreshing my APIC skills and extending them. Rather than use the Ubuntu vm where the Toolkit is installed, I have been using it in Windows 10, and accessing the APIM and CMC from Firefox and Chrome in Windows, using the ip address of the vm.

I have come to the conclusion that there must be a config value in the CMC or Portal, that forces Portal to only accepts urls containing 'developer.think.ibm'. Using the ip-address, also fails from Firefox in Ubuntu. In Windows, I added 'developer.think.ibm' to my hosts file and now I can access the Portal. Using vmware's NAT port forwarding 'localhost:4443', returns a 404.

It seems to me that inital access to the Portal, by its nature, should be easy, as this is the whole point of having an API manager.

Regards, John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Portal Server hosts multiple Portal sites (each Catalog has its own Portal site). The IP address of the server doesn't identify a site so you need to use the site's url (which is configured as part of the catalog configuration in API Manager).  URLs for different sites may have different virtual hosts, or differ only in their paths.

Comment: Thanks @SJC. 
What you said clarified this topic. I created a new Catalog and it would not allow me to re-use the host/domain name. 
I've never looked in detail at what comes in on a http request - I assumed any host or domain name would have been changed to the ip address. I now assume that doesn't happen - which means that the Portal does see the host/domain name. 
I have seen config options for DNS - but I haven't found any guidance on the item. 
Detailed tutorial guidance is hard to find for local cloud and DP Gateway - I use bits from here and there and then have to search my tabs.